# jQuery UI Sortable closest element with class after move

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get the data-group from the tr with a class of heading after a row has been moved using the jquery ui sortable plugin. i.e once it has been dragged its new position in the table I then need to access the closest('tr.heading').data('group') so I can make an ajax call to update my database.

No matter what I try the data attribute always returns undefined. I can console.log data-some-id so I know I have access to the element.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/168mxtw7/)

```
<table id="sort">
<tbody>
<tr class="heading" data-group="1" data-something-else="2">
   <td colspan="4">Group 1</td>
</tr>
<tr data-some-id="1" class="index">
   <td>Some Id</td>
   <td>Some Name</td>
   <td>Some description</td>
   <td>Some action</td>
</tr>
<tr data-some-id="2" class="index">
   <td>Some Id 2</td>
   <td>Some Name 2</td>
   <td>Some description 2</td>
   <td>Some action 2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-some-id="3" class="index">
   <td>Some Id 3</td>
   <td>Some Name 3</td>
   <td>Some description 3</td>
   <td>Some action 3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="heading" data-group="2" data-something-else="2">
   <td colspan="4">Group 2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-some-id="4" class="index">
   <td>Some Id 4</td>
   <td>Some Name 4</td>
   <td>Some description 4</td>
   <td>Some action 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-some-id="5" class="index">
   <td>Some Id 5</td>
   <td>Some Name 5</td>
   <td>Some description 5</td>
   <td>Some action 5</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>

<script>
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
        var originals = tr.children();
        var helper = tr.clone();
        helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width(originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return helper;
    },
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {

        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });

        console.log('product id = ' +  $(ui.item).attr('data-some-id'));
        console.log('Some Group = ' + $(ui.item).closest(".heading").attr("data-group"));
    }

   $("#sort tbody").sortable({
     helper: fixHelperModified,
     stop: updateIndex
   }).disableSelection();
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the tbody that you are calling?

Comment: @HoratioNullbuilt it is in there just left off in my recreation will edit code in question to reflect

Comment: This selector is definitely wrong - $('td.index') so try fixing that portion and see what result you'll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't at first understood what were you looking for, so here is the updated and hopefully right solution.

So yes, your initial selector was wrong, so after changing `td` to `tr`, sorting functionality started to work.

```
$('tr.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).html(i + 1);
});
```

The other problem that you've reported is that your table is messed up, and that was caused by the second line in the above function because you were basically replacing your table elements with plain numbers.

So instead of line `$(this).html(i + 1)`, I've replaced that with this code portion:

```
$(this).html(`
    <tr data-some-id="${i + 1}" class="index">
        <td>Some Id ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>Some Name ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>Some description ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>Some action ${i + 1}</td>
    </tr>`);
```

And finally to answer your last question, to get values for table rows with classes index and heading use this code:

```
console.log('product id = ' +  $(ui.item).attr('data-some-id'));
console.log('Some Group = ' + $(ui.item).prevAll("tr.heading").first().attr("data-group"));
```

Here is the complete solution - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea4dq20p/)

Comment: doesn't work for me? the table breaks and still doesn't return the id in the console the outer function updateIndex is the one we need